# Mongodb: Upgrade Mongo on Ubuntu Server When Instance is controlled by other ubuntu user

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, devops

I inherited a project from a departed developer.

I am trying to upgrade the mongo instance we currently use. Unfortunately, when run `mongod` I get this error:

`Mon May 18 13:25:39.475 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Mon May 18 13:25:39.475 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Mon May 18 13:25:39.475 [initandlisten] now exiting`

That's because I the instance of mongo currently in use is being controlled by another user created on the server `mongodb`. Also, when I try to look at the config file and all the directories and files the instance uses they are also controlled by `mongodb`, here's a `ls-la` output:

`drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb nogroup       4096 May 18 10:32 journal`

This was probably done for security purposes and I am ok with keeping it that way.

What I want to know is:

- How can I switch myself to act as the `mongodb` user (already tried `sudo su mongodb` with no success
- Or how can I upgrade the mongo instance from my current root user?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have root on the machine? If so I don't understand the problem.

Comment: I also getting same error. I have install ubuntu 14.04 inside windows 7 using virtual box. Windows also installed the mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with this. I wasn't upgrading properly. Here's the code to run your own code:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
cd /var/lib/mongodb/
sudo rm mongod.lock
cd /
sudo mkdir data
cd data/
sudo mkdir db
sudo service mongodb restart`

Run this and you'll be able to update/access your mongo as well